# EF 4.1 Code First POCOs Library

Tags: c#, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I would like to mention that i am new to EF.

I am creating the Data Access library with EF 4.1.

For each Entity I have two tables for translation target.

ex : Events  ==>  Event_ar for Arabic and Event_en for English.

**First Problem** : I have an error if i write two DbSets of same Entity Type

so I did this work around which is absolutely not nice :

```
public class Event_en : Event { }
public class Event_ar : Event { }

public class DB : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Event_ar> Events_ar { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Event_en> Events_en { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to know if there is a solution for it?

**Second one**
  The Entity should be same name as a table, otherwise i have an error.

Ex : "dbo.Event_ar" should have a POCO "Event_ar"

It should be the name of the property that has the same name of the table.

Here : dbo.Events_ar  ==> POCO "Events_ar"

Why I can't manipulate the names? Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if your solution is going in the right direction. It doesn't feel right to have a table for every language - you could simply add another column to the event table that specifies what the language is?

The you could use this column to retrieve the row with the desired language.

About tables and POCO entity names, you can override the table the entity is mapped to either through the use of a System.ComponentModel.TableAttribute at the class elvel, but to maintain POCO-ness I like to use EntityTypeConfiguration classes and specify the table name.

for example:

```
public class CurrencyConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Currency>
    {
        public CurrencyConfiguration()
        {
            this.ToTable("Conv", "Ref");           
        }
    }
```

Then you add it to the model builder in the OnModelCreating override method on the DbContext.

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Currency> Currencies { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CurrencyConfiguration());           
    }
}
```